# what does this function do and what does it mean ?`

Tags: function

I'm trying to understand what each line of this code does e.g. why is the `$` there and what does it do?, can anyone help?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head> 
<script>
i=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

    if(i==1){   
    document.getElementById("tf1").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf2") .setAttribute("fill", "yellow");
        i=2;
     }else if (i==2){
    document.getElementById("tf2").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf3") .setAttribute("fill", "green");
    i=3;
      } else if(i==3) {
    document.getElementById("tf3").setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    document.getElementById("tf1").setAttribute("fill", "red") ;
        i=1;
    }       

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The $ is telling the document that it is jQuery function/code. the rest of the code is saying: the value of i is 1. Then it is checking: if i=1 it is setting those attributes and resetting the value of i to 2. Next it is doing the same thing if i=2. Then it is checking: if i=1 it is setting those attributes and resetting the value of i to 3. And the same for i=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$- is for defining/accessing jQuery.

$(document) - means your whole file is under consideration.
$("button") - means all buttons in your document.

Now the code,
If the button is clicked and i is 1, then any element with id tf1 will have transparent color and any element with id tf2 will have yellow color.Then set i to 2.

If the button is clicked and i is 2, then any element with id tf2 will have transparent color and any element with id tf3 will have green color. Then set i to 3.

If the button is clicked and i is 3, then any element with id tf3 will have transparent color and any element with id tf1 will have red color.Then set i to 1.

So, whenever a button is clicked the value of i will be set different every time and your document elements with those ids will change their color every time.

Comment: no it does not :) If you are unfamiliar with jQuery this is a best place to start with http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ it has a very easy-going tutorial.

Comment: if i did use assests where will they be best located ?